# what is the alternative of CFRelease

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

If we dont use CFRelease using ARC what is the alternative.If we Use ARC then CFRelease is throwing the error.I have tried with _bridge and _bridge_transfer both are not working.

Comment: I am not expecting any comment from H2CO3 i.e from the user "Nikolai Ruhe" If and only If it is a Constructive I will accept else I will not accept.

Comment: Sorry if I'm beating @H2CO3 to the punch, but... this question isn't specific enough to help us diagnose your problem. Post some code, and some description of what/where/how it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no alternative to `CFRelease`. `CFRelease` is necessary, ARC or not. ARC manages ObjC objects *only*.

In some cases, the frameworks may provide a more specialized release for a certain type (e.g. `CGContextRelease`), but really there is no alternative.

`CFRelease` states it is an error to pass `NULL`. If that is the error you see and you do not want this behavior, you can always write your own wrapper function which first tests the parameter before passing.

If you have a more specific error or more specific problem, we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use some Core Foundation and Objective-C objects within your code interchangeably, but without seeing any code, I can't say for sure what's happening. However, there's a very important clarification that needs mentioning in case you weren't already aware:

ARC only automatically manages memory for Objective-C objects, which is why you don't need to call `release` anymore. Accordingly, ARC does *not* automatically manage memory for Core Foundation objects, which is why you would use `CFRelease()`.

Comment: *If you try to use CFRelease() on an Objective-C object, you'll get an error.* -- That's not true. Of course, it is an error if there is a reference count *imbalance*.

Comment: I am adding these lines of code NSString   NSString *lObjContactNumberLabelPtr = (NSString *)nil;
lObjContactNumberLabelPtr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(pPhonePropertyPtr, i);
lObjContactInfoPtr = [lObjContactNumberLabelPtr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_$!<" withString:@""];
CFRelease(
);